# Exception: Invalid image data - using CachedNetworkImage

Tags: flutter

I use CachedNetworkImage and get the error "Invalid image data", despite the url link works in the browser

```
   ======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
    The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
    Exception: Invalid image data
    
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5886:5)
    #1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5741:12)
    #2      instantiateImageCodecFromBuffer (dart:ui/painting.dart:2092:60)
    #3      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodecFromBuffer (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:153:15)
    #4      ImageLoader.loadBufferAsync.<anonymous closure> (package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:68:22)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #5      ImageLoader._load (package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:121:25)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #6      new MultiImageStreamCompleter.<anonymous closure> (package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/multi_image_stream_completer.dart:25:18)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

Code:

```
    CachedNetworkImage(
     placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
       width: 100,
       height:  100,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
     ),
     errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Material(child: Icon(Icons.broken_image, size:  20,),),
     imageUrl: _url,
    ),
```

Comment: Can you share Image URL?

Comment: Check your image url, it cause issue.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to check if imageurl is null or note like,

```
_url!=null?
 CachedNetworkImage(
     placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
       width: 100,
       height:  100,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
     ),
     errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Material(child: Icon(Icons.broken_image, size:  20,),),
     imageUrl: _url,
    )
:Image.assets("your local image here");
```

show CachedNetworkImage only when your image url is not null use any local image instead.

Comment: the url is not null, when I print url I can click on it and everything is fine in browser

Comment: ohk so..then you have you check that image url is valid or you are passing valid url?

Comment: how do I check if the url is valid? I thought if I can open the url in browser it‘s valid

Comment: I have this error too and it is said because of dart VM itself not recognizing the error as a caught exception. Even if the url is null, it should be able to display the error widget but because of the dart VM, it pause the debugging. there is issue filed for this here is the link [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16592). There is also [link](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47692) and [link](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/600).